# docker: mkDir command not creating folder

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile

Im new to docker and Want to create a logs folder inside app directory. It created the app directory but creating logs folder inside ap directory not working. I tried building image and run it in local it created the logs folder inside app dir, but in server its not creating the logs folder. pls help.... Following is my docker file.

```
FROM node:14

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /var/www/test-app-api/

# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
# where available (npm@5+)
COPY package*.json ./

#RUN npm install
# If you are building your code for production
RUN npm ci --only=production

RUN mkdir -p /var/www/test-app-api/logs

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "node", "server.js" ]
```

Comment: What causes you to think the log directory isn't being created?  How are you starting the container?  (If you're mounting some external content over the `/var/www/test-app-api` directory, that will hide everything this Dockerfile does, and I'd suggest removing those mounts.)

Answer (score 0):

In line 4, You are creating a working directory and locating yourself in this folder. Then  you are creating another folder from this folder, so the new folder is created on this path:

```
/var/www/test-app-api/var/www/test-app-api/logs
```

What should you do is replace the command steps or change the `RUN mkdir -p /var/www/test-app-api/logs` to `RUN mkdir -p /logs`

Answer (score 0):

WORKDIR is not the correct instruction.
From the official site:

> The WORKDIR instruction sets the working directory for any RUN, CMD, ENTRYPOINT, COPY and ADD instructions that follow it in the Dockerfile. If the WORKDIR doesn’t exist, it will be created even if it’s not used in any subsequent Dockerfile instruction.

So in your case it creates the `/var/www/test-app-api/` folder but it also set this directory as the working directory for the COPY, RUN and CMD instructions.

Because of that the instruction `RUN mkdir -p /var/www/test-app-api/logs` will create a folder of `/var/www/test-app-api/logs` under `/var/www/test-app-api/` so you will get the following folder: `/var/www/test-app-api/logs/var/www/test-app-api/` which is not what you want.

To get what you want change the `WORKDIR /var/www/test-app-api/` to  `RUN mkdir /var/www/test-app-api/`.

But, if you want the `COPY` instructions to be in `/var/www/test-app-api/` so stay with the WORKDIR but change the `RUN mkdir -p /var/www/test-app-api/logs` to `RUN mkdir -p logs`

Comment: `mkdir -p /var/www/...` uses an absolute path, so it won't be interpreted relative to the current `WORKDIR`; it should create exactly the directory that's named.  I might use shorter paths but the basic command sequence in the Dockerfile seems fine.